# Line receiving and processing with `asyncio.Protocol`?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am considering using `asyncio.Protocol` for implementing a line oriented protocol, but it only has `data_received()` method.

I am trying to avoid line buffering and processing myself. Twisted has [`LineReceiver`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/9.0.0/api/twisted.protocols.basic.LineReceiver.html) class with a method called `lineReceived()`. Is there something similar in Python standard `asyncio` library?

Comment: What about [StreamReader.readline](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.StreamReader.readline)?

Comment: @Vincent `reader` can be used when already using streams. It sounds like the OP wants to implement a custom `Protocol` subclass with the goal to enrich it with methods coresponding protocol-specific events (analogous to adding `headers_received` or `body_data_received` methods for an http `Protocol`). This is how `asyncio.Protocol` was designed to be used, and it's what comes naturally to someone coming from Twisted.

Comment: Unfortunately asyncio doesn't come with a rich set of helpers to write such classes - transports and protocols are considered low-level and if you're using them, you are expected to do your own buffering. Most users in turn only care about the streaming layer, and that's what libraries such as aiohttp expose. I haven't checked the new asyncio docs, but the old ones didn't do a great job of making the point that protocols should be rarely need in day-to-day asyncio programming.